# Unix Permission Setting Speed

Tags: linux, security, unix, file-permissions

Is there any significant speed difference between adding/subtracting a permission and explicitly setting it?

For example:

```
chmod a+r
```

vs

```
chmod 755
```

Comment: You may have more luck asking at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.  The absolute setting requires a single system call (`chmod()`).  The incremental setting requires two calls — one to get the current permissions (`stat()`) and then `chmod()` to set them.  The `chmod()` system call only deals in absolute settings.

Having said "there is a difference", I would be surprised if it was often a measurable difference.  The work done by the `stat()` call to load the path would prime the kernel to handle the `chmod()` call on the same file name rather fast. However, if you are working with network files, especially over a WAN, then it is conceivable that the network file system might make a measurable difference.